# jQuery perform function when element class changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I've set up a [swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/) slider and would like to set off a function when it gets to a specific slide. This is what I've done so far but it isn't working:

```
// event listener
 function addClassNameListener(elemId, callback) {
    var elem = $(".swiper-home .swiper-slide:nth-child(2)");
    var activeClassName = 'swiper-slide-active';
    window.setInterval( function() {   
     var className = elem.className;
      if (className == activeClassName) {
        callback();   
      }
    },10);
  }

addClassNameListener("foo", function(){ 
  $('.swiper-slide-active .count').each(function () {
    //$('body').scrollTop($(this).parent.offset().top);
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
      Counter: $(this).data().total
    }, {
      duration: $(this).data().seconds * 1000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function (now) {
        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
      }
    });
  });
  alert("changed"); 

});
```

I've set up a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4gtcn5Lt/1/)

Comment: Your `elem` variable is a jQuery object, so it doesn't have a `.className` property - you could change the test to `if (elem.hasClass(activeClassName))`, thereby fixing that problem *and* allowing for elements with multiple classes. Also your `addClassNameListener()` function doesn't use its `elemId` parameter.

Comment: Hi @nnnnnn, thank you for this but I've just tried it and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually several things you are doing wrong.

You are accessing `className` on a `elem` while it is a jquery object, not a dom element, so it doesn't have this property. Even if it would, it would give all classes separated with spaces, so you should better check
`elem.hasClass(activeClassName)`

Even with that, your callback function will be executed every 10 milliseconds no matter slide was changed or not

If you look at the [api](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/) of the swiper library you are using, you can use what's provided by them.

E.g. take active slide on slide changed event:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    onSlideChangeEnd: function(swiper) {
        var $activeSlide = $(swiper.slides[swiper.activeIndex]);
        //check if this slide is the one you are looking for
        if ($activeSlide.attr('id') == elemId)
        {
            //do your stuff with the active slide
        }
   }
});
```